# Is there a way to control distortion in Matlab's 3D viewer?

Tags: matlab, opengl, 3d

The background of this problem relates to my attempt to combine output from a ray tracer with Matlab's 3d plotters. When doing ray tracing, there is no need to apply a perspective transformation to the rendered image. You see this in the image below. Basically, the intersections of the rays with the viewport will automatically adjust for the perspective scaling.

[image: ray tracer]

Suppose I've gone and created a ray-traced image (so I am given my camera, my focal length, viewport dimensions, etc.). How do I create exactly the same view in Matlab's 3d plotting environment?

Here is an example:

```
clear
close all

evec = [0 200 300]; % Camera position

recw = 200;         % cm width of box
recl = 200;         % cm length of box
h = 150;            % cm height of box

% Create the front face rectangle
front = zeros(3,5);
front(:,1) = [-recw/2; 0; -recl/2];
front(:,2) = [recw/2; 0; -recl/2];
front(:,3) = [recw/2; h; -recl/2];
front(:,4) = [-recw/2; h; -recl/2];
front(:,5) = front(:,1);

% Back face rectangle
back = zeros(3,5);
back(:,1) = [-recw/2; 0; recl/2];
back(:,2) = [recw/2; 0; recl/2];
back(:,3) = [recw/2; h; recl/2];
back(:,4) = [-recw/2; h; recl/2];
back(:,5) = back(:,1);

% Plot the world view
figure(1);
patch(front(1,:), front(2,:), front(3,:), 'r'); hold all
patch(back(1,:), back(2,:), back(3,:), 'b');
plot3(evec(1), evec(2), evec(3), 'bo');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
title('world view'); view([-30 40]);

% Plot the camera view
figure(2);
patch(front(1,:), front(2,:), front(3,:), 'r'); hold all
patch(back(1,:), back(2,:), back(3,:), 'b');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
title('Camera view');


campos(evec);
camup([0 1 0]); % Up vector is y+
camproj('perspective');
camtarget([evec(1), evec(2), 0]);
title('camera view');
```

Now you see the world view

[image: world view]

and the camera view

[image: camera view]

I know how to adjust the camera position, the camera view angle, and orientation to match the output from my ray tracer. However, I do not know how to adjust Matlab's built-in perspective command

```
camproj('perspective')
```

for different distortions.

Note: within the documentation, there is the `viewmtx` command, which allows you to output a transformation matrix corresponding to a perspective distortion of a certain angle. This is not quite what I want. I want to do things in 3D and through Matlab's OpenGL viewer. In essence, I want a command like

```
camproj('perspective', distortionamount)
```

so I can match up the amount of distortion in Matlab's viewer with the distortion from the ray tracer. If you use the viewmtx command to create the 2D projections, you will not be able to use `patch' or`surf' and keep colours and faces intact.

Comment: Damn, trying to hack Matlab, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB perspective projection works just like your raytracer. You don't need any transformation matrices to it use it. Perspective distortion is determined entirely by the camera position and direction of projection.

In the terminology of the raytracer diagram above, if the `CameraPosition` matches your raytracer's pinhole coordinates and the vector between `CameraPosition` and `CameraTarget` is perpendicular to your raytracer's viewport, the perspective distortion will also match. The rest is just scaling and alignment.